# Time slot selection and displaying in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, selection, slot

Guys please give suggestions on how to get the result as you can see in the pic2 when I give input as in pic1.

Please help me, I am new to rails and need your suggestion. Thanks in advance

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/593/11072918.jpg/ 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/822/76461672.jpg/

In Pic1 the user has to choose the time for appointments/reservation and the result should show in Pic2 as dots in the calendar format.

It doesn't need to be exactly same as in the pics. 
Can somebody please give some better ideas.

Comment: This question is too broad. What part of this task are you not sure how to do? what have you tried already?

Comment: There is nothing broad in it one user has to choose the time slots according to which the time slots will get updated in the image as shown in pic 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either implement it in js yourself or try to find an js-based-framework with functionality which is suitable for this task.

as i saw your screenshots it reminds me somehow of [smartgwt](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/) grids and stuff, it can be used with rails [rails and smartgwt](http://railsblog.kieser.net/2010/01/netbeans-ruby-on-rails-smartgwt-and.html) but needs some effort